# Find Those Chess Notations! #4

Tags: chess, retrograde-analysis

Yes, it’s back again! This one is going to be a little different however.

Number Of Moves: 11

Checkmater: White

Final Position:

[image]

Cryptic Clue #1: Not all is as it seems!

Cryptic Clue #2: Are you kidding me?!

Task: You must find a series of moves that leads to the given final position. They must be posted In algebraic notation, in a PGN format. You must also include reasons on why each move is at you state it to be, along with reasoning for the cryptic clues.

Good luck, and go find those notations!

Comment: By the number of moves being 11, do you mean the number of moves for white or number of overall steps (each step being 1 move from white and 1 move from black)? I presume you mean the latter, but puzzlers here can get a little picky ;)

Comment: @user477343 Well in chess, both white and black act in one move; a single action by white or black is a half-move.

Comment: @noedne I know, but for the sake of other users who didn't know this in particular, though perhaps knew of the game chess, I wanted to clarify this, so thanks for your comment! :P

Comment: @user477343 I think the clarification is good, but it sounds like the two interpretations in your question are the same. Did you mean for one of them to be 11 total moves, where one move is a move by white or black?

Comment: I meant to ask which interpretation was it out of the following: one move made by either side was counted as 1 move, or two consecutive moves each made by either side was counted as 1 move.

Comment: Incidentally, this puzzle is harder than it looks! I can do it in 13, but not 11 (...yet)

Comment: @RewanDemontay I was planning not to because it takes time and it isn't the answer, but perhaps I might give other users ideas, so I'll do that. Of course, I am going to have to include a retrograde analysis and a few images... but I won't unless I get the answer. Hope that's okay with you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Solution, using a very specific definition of a rule of chess

I can solve this puzzle, if I use

> the castling rule according to the pre-1972 FIDE castling rules, which allows castling along the e-file, as mentioned here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castling#cite_note-3

Assuming I use that rule, here is a solution:

> 1. e4 d5
>
>  2. exd5 Kd7
>
>  3. d6 Kc6
>
>  4. Bb5+ Kxb5
>
>  5. c4+ Kxc4
>
>  6. dxe7 Kd3
>
>  7. Qe2+ Kc2
>
>  8. Qf1 Nf6
>
>  9. d4 Nfd7
>
>  10. e8=R h6
>
>  11. 0-0-0-0-0-0#
>
>  The final move uses 6 zeros to indicate that the rook moved 6 squares down the e-file while castling, instead of the 2 in kingside castling and 3 in queenside castling

Comment: @RewanDemontay I don't have any special explanation for those clues - I just interpreted them as saying that an unusual rule was used, as mentioned in my answer. If anything else was meant, I missed it.

Comment: Did the position of the king and rook also give the answer to you?

Comment: @RewanDemontay Yes, I've seen this mechanic before

Comment: Agh, dang! You got it before me! ;)

Comment: This mechanic is also discussed [here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/18083/is-castling-possible-with-a-pawn-promoted-to-a-rook).

Answer (score 1):

## Partial Answer

Here is what I got thus far: 13 moves. It is definitely not the right answer, and some moves there look like a "waste of a move" really, but I tried to narrow it down, though I couldn't. This is my best shot at the moment. I think it is along the lines of these moves (i.e. at least one of them is correct, I believe) hence I am posting it here for some inspiration, I suppose.

> [image: Chess] 
>  Moves 11-12 starting from black's move looks like a waste of a move, but I had to get the king to the e3 square, so something like this was my best option, as far as I could tell. It definitely is quite a difficult puzzle! (That's a compliment, by the way.)

Comment: @RewanDemontay I should be going to sleep now, because it is very late for me... so late in fact, it is not very early! *But...* seeing that I'm on the right track has tempted me to stay up that extra bit and try finishing this off. (If I don't change my answer within the next hour, I've zonked out.) :P

Comment: Typo: I was meant to say it is *now* very early (boy, I have not slept at all and it's reaching 4:30am) but that's besides the point. I just hate typos, is all. Thanks for the cryptic clues, nevertheless! :)

Comment: @RewanDemontay Gah, humbug! Guess I'm gonna have to work on this tomorrow. Nice puzzle, and g'night! :)